# URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL when publishing branch

Tags: github, branch, project, publish, github-desktop

I am trying to publish a branch from Github Desktop but I get this weird error: URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL. I have searched all around the internet and can't find a solution. Does anyone know how to fix it or why this error occurs?

Answer (score 4):

I had this error because I added a bit wrong url locally to remote origin with

```
git remote add origin https://url:user/my-repo.git
```

Checked the remote origin locally and compared to cloning repo url

```
git remote show origin
fatal: unable to access 'https://...': URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

I had to replace semicolon '**:**' with backslash '**/**' in front of username. Locally had to remove remote origin, then add back

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin https://url/user/my-repo.git
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the remote url of github repo? Please also check the remote name. By default it should be `origin`

It can be done as follows:

In your repo, run `git remote -v` and match the url returned with that of the "clone" url of your repo. If its different please update it to "clone" url of your repo locally.

And then try hitting:

```
git push origin <branch name>
```

Comment: I found the solution! I had to reassign the url for it to work. I don't know why it works now but it works!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Apparently you can use this command and it needs to be in this format, I am using an access key:

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://<access key>@github.com/<user name>/<reponame>.git
```

Try that and see if that helps.